# Install java on Centos 7 and Command not known error

Tags: java, java-8, centos7

I downloaded JDK8U171 and copy it to /opt/jdk1.8.0_171/. I installed it by these commands :

```
alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk1.8.0_171/bin/java 2
alternatives --config java
```

after this java -version worked perfectly

```
java version "1.8.0_171"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)
```

all these works were done by root. In my user account when I enter java -version I got /usr/bin/java : Permission denied but when I use

```
usermod a+x /usr/bin/java
```

I get command not known. I exported $PATH = $PATH:/opt/jdk1.8.0_171/bin but it's not useful.
which java also returns /usr/bin/which: no java in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/home/esadeghi/.local/bin:/home/esadeghi/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_171/bin:/usr/bin/java:/opt/jdk1.8.0_171/bin)

Comment: This seems more suitable for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to grant read permissions to your user with chmod and/or assign your user to the group and grant the permissions.

Also, you can install JDK (or JRE) using **yum** installer it should assign proper permissions automatically.

Or you can just download binary package from Oracle website, then unzip it to any appropriate folder and grant full read permissions (chmod -R 777 /jdk1.8.0_171) to the folder for everyone.

Comment: I don't have access to Oracle web site because of US sanctions.